# how do we can make amazon like search suggestions using elasticsearch (note:amazon is using elasticsearch )

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

[this is what exactly I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoB73.png)

Am using elastic search , my suggestion is working but I need a search suggestion like amazon. is it possible using elastic search.

Comment: how you know amazon is using Elasticsearch ?

Comment: yeah.. amazon and some big companies are using elastic search...

Comment: As far as I know, Amazon is not using Elasticsearch for their main site search :)

Comment: but can we do like that using elasticsearch

Comment: is there any other module in python to do like that